# Setting direction of rotation in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a circle with few clickable points. When I click one of these, I want it to rotate to the right side (zero degree) position. When I click the point on top (90deg), I want the circle to rotate clockwise and when I click the point at the bottom, (270deg), I want it to rotate anti-clockwise. Essentially, take the shortest path to get to right side. The problem is, when I click the bottom  point (blue star), the circle takes the longest path to be at the right side. If you play around with it a bit more, you can see that it seems to set a specific direction to each point and no matter where they are, it follows that direction.

How do I control that direction of rotation please? Any pointers towards this is appreciated.

```js
function rotate(angle) {
  d3.select('.container')
    .attr('transform', `rotate(${angle})`);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  transform-origin: 250px 250px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.star {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star--red {
  fill: red;
}

.star--green {
  fill: green;
}

.star--blue {
  fill: lightblue;
}

.star--pink {
  fill: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewbox="0 0 500 500"> 
 <g class="container">
  <ellipse id="main-circle" stroke-width="2" ry="145" rx="145" cy="250" cx="250" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/> 
  <path id="svg_8" class="star star--red" onclick="rotate(90);" 
        d="m228.500007,135.025599l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075348,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643555l-13.287804,9.643555l5.075609,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/>
  <path id="svg_9" class="star star--green" onclick="rotate(180);"
        d="m119.362495,245.178355l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075347,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643556l-13.287805,9.643556l5.07561,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/>
  <path id="svg_10"  class="star star--blue" onclick="rotate(270);"
 d="m228.500007,355.025599l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075347,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643556l-13.287805,9.643556l5.07561,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/> 
  <path id="svg_11" class="star star--pink" onclick="rotate(0);"
 d="m337.362495,245.178355l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075347,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643556l-13.287805,9.643556l5.07561,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

<sup>Essentially I've copy pasted the codepen code here, but the pen is also available at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjMVzM</sup>

Comment: Have you tried  -90 deg?

Comment: @magjac Yes, making `star--blue` -90deg doesn't work when blue star is on top. It rotates anti clock wise instead of clockwise

Comment: You asked how to control the direction of the rotation, not how to fix your code. Don't forget to thank @Andrew for doing that for you.

Comment: @magjac no need to be condescending, I didn't understand the problem myself completely, which is the whole point of asking. If you didn't want to fix my code, all you had to do was explain what I had to do and I would me more than happy to work with it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. That was uncalled for. I apologize. I could have helped you faster if you had described what you already had tried though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just get away with tracking only the required rotation, you also need to keep track of the total rotation. For example, If you keep clicking whatever star is on top the required degrees to keep going becomes, `[0, 90, 180, 270, 360, 450, ...]`. Once keeping track of the total rotation, all you need to do is determine the direction to increment as shown below.

```js
var totAngle = 0;
function rotate(angle) {
  d3.select('.container')
    .attr('transform', () => {
      // Clamp the current rotation to 0-360
      var minAngle = ((totAngle % 360) + 360) % 360;
      // Calculate the required rotation 0/90/180/270
      var rot = (angle - minAngle + 360) % 360;
      // Determine the direction clockwise/counter-clockwise
      totAngle += rot <= 180 ? rot : -90
      return `rotate(${totAngle})`;
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  transform-origin: 250px 250px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.star {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star--red {
  fill: red;
}

.star--green {
  fill: green;
}

.star--blue {
  fill: lightblue;
}

.star--pink {
  fill: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewbox="0 0 500 500"> 
 <g class="container">
  <ellipse id="main-circle" stroke-width="2" ry="145" rx="145" cy="250" cx="250" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/> 
  <path id="svg_8" class="star star--red" onclick="rotate(90);" 
        d="m228.500007,135.025599l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075348,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643555l-13.287804,9.643555l5.075609,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/>
  <path id="svg_9" class="star star--green" onclick="rotate(180);"  d="m119.362495,245.178355l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075347,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643556l-13.287805,9.643556l5.07561,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/>
  <path id="svg_10"  class="star star--blue" onclick="rotate(270);"
 d="m228.500007,355.025599l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075347,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643556l-13.287805,9.643556l5.07561,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/> 
  <path id="svg_11" class="star star--pink" onclick="rotate(0);"
 d="m337.362495,245.178355l16.424656,0l5.075345,-15.603354l5.075347,15.603354l16.424653,0l-13.287801,9.643293l5.075608,15.603354l-13.287807,-9.643556l-13.287805,9.643556l5.07561,-15.603354l-13.287806,-9.643293z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, for helping me understand the problem!

Answer (score 1):

To rotate counter-clockwise, use a negative angle.

Comment: Upvoted because it does answer the title. Clearly, I asked what I thought was the solution instead of stating the problem.